# How to trace the initiator in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Let's say that I have file based routing of a single-page application, and lets say that I loaded `ProfileProjects.page.tsx` route.

I want to understand why this particular route also loaded another module, e.g. `react-easy-crop`.

[image]

I can begin doing this by find `react-easy-crop` bundle in Network tab and looking at the Initiator. It tells me that it was loaded because of `ProjectThumbnailPicker.tsx`. So now... I need to know what loaded `ProjectThumbnailPicker.tsx`. Rinse and repeat, and eventually I will know which component in `ProfileProjects.page.tsx` resulted in loading this package.

I recorded a quick video explaining in more detail:

https://www.loom.com/share/c3b65dc0672240e599b50436c527c1c0

Is there a shortcut in Chrome to show the entire trace?, i.e. seeing initiator path all the way to the top level script.

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered that there is "Initiator" tab that shows the entire chain!

[image]